# Alternate to Sling JSP recompile for Sightly/HTL?

Tags: aem, apache-felix, sling

Is there any alternate feature similar to sling JSP recompile button in OSGI Felix console for HTL/Sightly components code refresh.?

`http://host:port/system/console/slingjsp`
[image: Sling JSP]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I don't see any such kind of feature like one button click trigger to recompile options for the Sightly in AEM. but you can use **Development Mode** check box enabled in **Apache Sling Scripting Sightly Engine Configuration** at Felix console which results Sightly components recompilation at every request. have a look at [sightly documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scripting/scripting-htl.html) for more information related to this. also from [grepcode for SightlyEngineConfiguration](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly/1.0.0/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/engine/SightlyEngineConfiguration.java)

[image: Sightly Engine Config]